# Convert Oracle CONNECT BY query to SQL Server query

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle

How to convert this Oracle code structure to SQL Server:

```sql
SELECT LEVEL, EMPNO, ENAME, JOB, MGR FROM EMP
CONNECT BY MGR = PRIOR EMPNO
START WITH MGR IS NULL
ORDER BY LEVEL;
```

Comment: Is it sql server or mysql?

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server does not have `CONNECT BY`. You need to use a recursive CTE.

Place the `START WITH` in the `WHERE` filter of the anchor part (the first part of the CTE).

In the recursive part (the second half), rejoin the CTE to `EMP` with the `CONNECT BY` condition.

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT
        LEVEL = 1,
        e.EMPNO,
        e.ENAME,
        e.JOB,
        e.MGR
    FROM EMP e
    WHERE e.MGR IS NULL

    UNION ALL

    SELECT
        cte.LEVEL + 1,
        e.EMPNO,
        e.ENAME,
        e.JOB,
        e.MGR
    FROM EMP e
    JOIN cte ON e.MGR = cte.EMPNO
)

SELECT
    cte.LEVEL,
    cte.EMPNO,
    cte.ENAME,
    cte.JOB,
    cte.MGR
FROM cte
ORDER BY cte.LEVEL;
```

Comment: is their a way to not to use cte , just using simple clauses like ( where,select,joint,union,group by,having )??

Comment: No, `CONNECT BY` is recursive by nature. I suppose you could do a `WHILE` loop but that is not likely to be easier or more performant